# Reduce boolean values in python ndarray using AND

Tags: python, numpy

I have a python array of this shape `[3, 1000, 3]` with boolean values inside. The first `3` is the batch size and the values of a batch are like these

```
[[False, False, False]\n
 [False, True, True]\n
 [False, False, True]\n
 [True, True, True]\n
 ...
]
size (1000, 3)
```

I want to apply the `and` function to each triplet to end up with this new array

```
[[False]\n
 [False]\n
 [False]\n
 [True]\n
 ...
]
size (3, 1000)
```

Looking at `numpy` I didn't find something useful. I've also tried to import `operator` and apply `reduce(operator.and_, array)` but it doesn't work.

Any idea to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily do this using [np.all](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.all.html).
This will check if all values along the last dimension are `True`:

```
y = np.all(arr, axis=-1)
y.shape # (3, 1000)
```